# on click event I am trying to get the data from XML as per the click object's attr() value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

on click event I am trying to get the data from XML as per the click object's attr() value.

Below I have placed two hyperlink buttons and a container for input the data. Both are having different attr() value.

So I want to get the data according to these hyperlink's attr() value.

Even I have created a XML with respective nodes.But unable to get the exact data. can anyone please help?

here is the JS and XML code:

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
        $('a.readmore').click(function() {

            var container = $('#uiWrapper');

            $.get('myxml3.xml',function(data){
                container.empty();
                $(data).find('sector').each(function(){
                    var $tag = $(this), 
                        getName = $('a.readmore').attr('href');

                    var html = '<div class="data">';                      
                        html += '<div class="tagDetail">' + $tag.find('description').text() + '</div>';
                        html += '</div>';   

                    if($tag.attr('name') == getName){
                        container.append(html);
                    }else{
                    return false;
                    }       


                });                        
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

XMLCode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sections>

  <sector name="mark">
  <description>Mark Text is coming</description>
  </sector>

  <sector name="source">
  <description>Source Text is coming</description>
  </sector>


</sections>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want by clicking on the link the description is display according to the href attribute of the link, your html page with script will be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $('#uiWrapper');
    $('a.readmore').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var getName=$(this).attr('href')
        container.empty();
        $.get('myxml3.xml', function(xml){
            $(xml).find('sector').each(function(){
                var $sector = $(this);
                var title = $sector.attr("name");
                if(title===getName){
                    var description = $sector.find('description').text();
                    var html='<div class="data"><div class="tagDetail">'+description+'</div></<div>'
                    $('#uiWrapper').append($(html));
                };
            });
        });
   });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="uiWrapper"></div>
<a class="readmore" href="mark">mark</a>
<a class="readmore" href="source">source</a>
</body>
</html>
```

For this example i use the xml file of your post
If you want to get the same result by using the $ajax method, your code will be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $('#uiWrapper');
    $('a.readmore').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var getName=$(this).attr('href')
        container.empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "myxml3.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(xml)
                var $xml = $(xmlDocument);
                $(xml).find('sector').each(function(){
                    var $sector = $(this);
                    var title = $sector.attr("name");
                    if(title===getName){
                        var description = $sector.find('description').text();
                        var html='<div class="data"><div class="tagDetail">'+description+'</div></<div>'
                        $('#uiWrapper').append($(html));
                    }
                })  
             }
        });

   });
});

</script>
```